# Identifying indices where any one of a plurality of columns has a certain value?

Tags: pandas, filtering

I need to determine which indices in a dataframe have any one of a set of columns having a specified value. The dataframe has several hundred columns, and a few dozen I need to use for the filtering, so it's impractical to write them all out. My strategy is as follows, to determine indices where any column having 'temp' in its name is equal to 1:

```
columns = [col for col in df.columns if 'temp' in col]
indices = list(np.where(df[columns]==1)[0])
```

However, this is returning an unexpected result - it seems return a value for every single index in the df. Any clues where this is going wrong?

Comment: One makeshift solution I thought of is just to create a separate df filtered to only the columns of interest (df_temp = df[columns]) and then find any rows with values of 1 in any column (df_temp.where(df_temp==1) ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Toy dataframe: two columns have "temp" in their name
# and rows 0 and 3 have a value of 1
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"SJDRtemp": [0, 0, 0, 1], "TR": [0, 0, 2, 1], "LDtemp": [1, 3, 0, 0]}
)

# Select columns which name contains "temp"
columns = [col for col in df.columns if "temp" in col]

# Get indices of rows where "temp columns" have a value of 1
indices = list(df[df[columns] == 1].dropna(how="all").index)

print(indices)
# Outputs
[0, 3]
```